# aiohttp how to save a persistent ClientSession in a class?

Tags: python, httprequest, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing a class that will do http requests using aiohttp. According to the docs I should not to create a ClientSession per request, so I want to reuse the same session.

code:

```
class TestApi:
   def __init__(self):
      self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

   # async defs methods from here
```

When doing

```
TestApi()
```

I get the error: `Unclosed client session`.

What is the solution to persist the `ClientSession` object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression `TestApi()` on a line by itself creates a `TestApi` object and immediately throws it away. `aiohttp` complaints that the session was never closed (either by leaving an `async with` block or with an explicit call to `close()`), but even without the warning it doesn't make sense not to assign the API object to a variable where it will be actually used.

To reuse the session, your code needs to have access to the session, or to an object that holds it:

```
async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.request('GET', url) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return await resp.read()

async def main():
    url1_data, url2_data = asyncio.gather(
        fetch('http://url1'), fetch('http://url2'))
    url3_data, url4_data = asyncio.gather(
        fetch('http://url3'), fetch('http://url4'))
```

One option is to add a `session` parameter to `fetch` (and other functions) and consistently call it with a session created in `main()`. A better option is to create an API class and convert the global functions like `fetch` to methods:

```
class Http:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *err):
        await self._session.close()
        self._session = None

    async def fetch(self, url):
        async with self._session.get(url) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            return await resp.read()
```

`main()` can still exist as a function, but it can consistently *use* the object that holds the session:

```
async def main():
    async with Http() as http:
        url1_data, url2_data = await asyncio.gather(
            http.fetch('http://url1'), http.fetch('http://url2'))
        url3_data, url4_data = await asyncio.gather(
            http.fetch('http://url3'), http.fetch('http://url4'))
```

In the above code, the `async with` statement is used to ensure that the session is closed whenever the scope is left.

Comment: Is it possible to detect when the Http class is destroyed (go out of scope) so I can manually close the session?

Comment: @user3599803 Not easily, because `session.close()` needs to be awaited (which the initial version of my answer neglected to do, fixed now). The recommended way is to use `async with`, so you don't forget to close it regardless of how you exit the function.

Comment: I've now edited the answer to demonstrate the usage of `async with` with a custom object.

Comment: Thanks, I do prefer to store it in my code instead of having large async block. Does it make sense to store it as a global variable `session` before `loop.run_forever()` in my code, and then to access it from other python modules?

Comment: @user3599803 The async block doesn't need to be large if you put it at the right place - e.g. a top-most function that just calls another function. You can put it in a global variable, but I think the loop needs to be running at the time. The answer shows what I consider the recommended pattern (and faithfully answers the title of the question), but YMMV.

Comment: Is the `self._session = None` truly necessary?

Comment: @LoBellin It's not, it's mostly for clarity. (Also, it might facilitate earlier freeing of in-memory data referenced by the session.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the resource after finished use. The most common way is to implement a close function.

```
class TestApi:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def close(self) -> None:
        await self.session.close()

    # async defs methods from here
```

When you use your class, you need to call this function at the end.

```
api = TestApi()
# Doing important api calls
await api.close()
```

Better yet, you can use context managers to do this automatically.

```
class TestApi:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "TestApi":
        return self

    async def __aexit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Exception,
        exc_val: TracebackException,
        traceback: TracebackType,
    ) -> None:
        await self.close()

    async def close(self) -> None:
        await self.session.close()

    # async defs methods from here
```

Then use it like so:

```
async with TestApi() as api:
    # Doing important api calls
    ...
```

Just remember, the class has to be initialized inside a task (async function). [You can read more at my answer on a similiar question at the aiohttp github repository](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4932#issuecomment-1611759696).